# jackson with JSON - just print out the entire response

Tags: java, jackson

using an ObjectMapper I can send out a JSON request.

However, the response i'm getting is some form of funky error - I'd really like to see the entire json string being returned by the remote server.

I know i can dummy up the request and look at that (via curl, say), but then that's not really helpful debugging my program.

So! How do i just print out the entire response as a string, given the request was sent using the  jackson ObjectMapper?

I don't want to make any objects to be bundling/unbundling - i'm trying to work out what the objects look like, hence wanting to see the string!

Comment: sigh. How rude to downvote or vote for close but not help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuck.

Looks like my lack of familiarity with Jackson & URL reading got the better of me.

Jackson won't do any such thing (I think!) but that's ok - typically you'd have given the inputstream to the ObjectMapper to play with.

eg

```
mapper.writeValue(connection.getOutputStream(), somePojoHere);
```

Given that that is the case, then just do this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedRead(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```